# Linear Independence of functions F(R)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ be functions in $F(R)$ (the set of real valued functions).
For the set of real numbers $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, let $f_i(x_j)$ be the 3 by 3 matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $f_i(x_j)$. Prove that if the rows of the matrix is linearly independent, then so is $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$.

My approach was that since each row is linearly independent, we can add other linearly independent sets so now I have 9 things in this set to span all the combinations of possible values of $f_i(x_j)$, hence this is a basis. Therefore, since $f_i(x)$ is a subset of this basis, as any subset of a linearly independent set is also linearly independent, then we have proven the question asked.

Is this correct? I am not comfortable with my approach. How can I do this question properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since each row is linearly independent

It doesn't make sense to say that a row is linearly independent. Linear independence is a property of a set of vectors and a row is a single vector. Linear independence refers to the *set of rows* of the matrix.

> we can add other linearly independent sets

You need to be clearer about what it means to "add sets". As written, this is nonsense.

> now I have 9 things in this set to span all the combinations of possible values of $f_i(x_j)$, hence this is a basis

The vector space of real valued functions is infinite dimensional, not 9-dimensional. The logic here is unclear and the conclusion, as written, is incorrect.

> since $f_i(x)$ is a subset of this basis, as any subset of a linearly independent set is also linearly independent

$f_i(x)$ isn't a set so it cannot be a subset. The set that I am assuming you mean is $\{ f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x) \}$ which is not a subset, since these are functions of $x$ (which is variable) whereas the elements of the matrix are the real numbers $f_i(x_j)$ (where $x_j$ is a fixed constant for each $j$).

---

How you want to approach this problem is through the contrapositive. That is, assume you have some linear relationship $$ a_1 f_1(x) + a_2 f_2(x) + a_3 f_3(x) \equiv 0 $$ where $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbf{R}$ are not all $0$ and $\equiv 0$ means that this is an identity in $x$ (i.e. it is true for all $x$). Now, using this linear relationship, show that the rows of the matrix $(f_i(x_j))$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you so much. There is so much flaw in my thinking, but I think I got it now!